# Two values of my struct do not print proper values

Tags: pointers, printing, struct

I have the following struct defined:

```
typedef struct word {
    const char *str;
    int freq;
    int edit_list;
} Word;
```

Inside my `main` function I use a pre-defined vector to store a collection of `Word` types (as defined in my struct above). The Vector named `corrections` has been defined and also has it's own iterator.

```
for(const Word *key = cvec_first(corrections); key != NULL; key = cvec_next(corrections, key)) {
    print("%s\n", key->str);
    print("%d\n", key->freq);
    print("%d\n", key->edit_dist);
}
```

The for loop iterateds through the collection of words and I am intending for it to print out each value of the `Word` struct. However, only the `str` type gets printed out properly, and the `freq` and `edit_dist` print out garbage values.

Comment: That's because you are using `%s` format for the non-string values. Use `%d` for `int` values.

Comment: Mike. That is just a typo that occured while I was hand coding in the StackOvflow editor.

Comment: Then the `int` values may simply be uninitialized?

Comment: Can you add the initialization code of the `vector` and the `Word` stored in it? it looks like the `int` are not initialized